# API hangs while building OData EdmModel, but only when deployed to Azure

Tags: asp.net-web-api, azure-web-app-service, .net-4.6.1

I have a ASP.NET Web API with OData running on .NET 4.6.1 and in an Azure App Service. During startup, it builds and registers an OData EdmModel for a couple very simple entities. It hangs while building the EdmModel, CPU usage spikes to 100%, becomes unresponsive, and the AppService eventually kills and restarts the process. This is a recent issue.

I've reduced it down to this example:

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    var odataBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
    odataBuilder.EntitySet<Foo>("Foos");
    var edmModel = builder.GetEdmModel(); // hangs here

    app.UseMvc(builder => builder.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "odata", edmModel, new DefaultODataBatchHandler());
}
```

Where `Foo` is a simple class with a handful of int, long, string, and DateTimeOffset fields. I've tried it with and without an associated controller at `odata/Foos`, with the same result either way.

Removing `odataBuilder.EntitySet<Foo>("Foos");` avoids the issue, but is obviously not very useful.

Any ideas to further troubleshoot this?

I've also updated the OData packages to the latest 7.x version. I should also note that this is a recent issue, and there haven't been any changes that are obviously related to this code.

Comment: .NET 4.6.1 is ***NOT*** .NET Core ....

Comment: @marc_s I'm using AspNetCore 2.x in a net461 project, [AspNetCore 2.x can target Net Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/introduction-to-aspnet-core?view=aspnetcore-2.2#aspnet-core-targeting-net-framework)

Comment: And ASP.NET Core 2.x support has ended in 2019 - I would **strongly urge** to upgrade to a current version - and those are either .NET (classic/legacy) or .NET Core - not mix and match

Comment: @schimmch can you please TargetFrameworkVersion

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Marc_s, yes as marc_s said Update the target framework in your project file to a more recent version, such as `net6.0` or later.

```
<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
```

[image]

- Integrated the `GetEdmModel` method to build and register the OData EdmModel. Build the `EdmModel` asynchronously to avoid blocking the main thread. The `GetEdmModel` method might be causing the hang due to synchronous execution.

**Program.cs:**

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Extensions;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.OData.Edm;

namespace WebApplication10
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

            // Add services to the container.
            builder.Services.AddControllers();
            builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
            builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

            var app = builder.Build();

            // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
            if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            // Build and register OData EdmModel
            var edmModel = GetEdmModel();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapODataRoute("odata", "odata", edmModel);
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });

            app.Run();
        }

        private static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
        {
            var odataBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
            odataBuilder.EntitySet<Foo>("Foos");
            return odataBuilder.GetEdmModel();
        }
    }
}
```

**OData message:**

[image]

- I also observed a typographical error in the variable names that you define the ODataConventionModelBuilder as `odataBuilder`, but then you attempt to get the EdmModel using `builder.GetEdmModel();`. This mismatch in variable names is likely causing the `NullReferenceException`, and the application hangs when trying to build the EdmModel.

**Code:**

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    var odataBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
    odataBuilder.EntitySet<Foo>("Foos");
    var edmModel = odataBuilder.GetEdmModel(); // Corrected variable name

    app.UseMvc(builder => builder.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "odata", edmModel, new DefaultODataBatchHandler()));
}
```